# JQuery , ajax ,mysql update when user logout

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Hello i have coded a script to update information ones user tries to logout but my code are not working and do not know why i need help to solve this :

jQuery :

```
$('#logout').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'updateusers.php',
        async: 'false'
    });
    alert(username);
});
```

so i am not sending any data with ajax because i call session in updateusers.php and insert session values , and test this code with alert(username); i got alerted ones i click on log out

this is my updateusers.php :

```
<?php
require "mysql.php";
session_start();

$userid = $_SESSION["userid"];
$usertyp = $_SESSION["usertype"];
$email = $_SESSION["email"];
$level = $_SESSION["level"];
$exp = $_SESSION["exp"];
$money = $_SESSION["money"] + 1000;
$ninjarank = $_SESSION["ninjarank"];
$avatar = $_SESSION["avatar"];
$village = $_SESSION["village"];
$clan = $_SESSION["clan"];
$guild = $_SESSION["guild"];
$healthpoint = $_SESSION["healthpoint"];
$chakrapoint = $_SESSION["chakrapoint"];
$ninjutsu = $_SESSION["ninjutsu"];
$taijutsu = $_SESSION["taijutsu"];
$genjutsu = $_SESSION["genjutsu"];
$senjutsu = $_SESSION["senjutsu"];
$talent = $_SESSION["talent"];
$chakra = $_SESSION["chakra"];
$health = $_SESSION["health"];
$chakracontrol = $_SESSION["chakracontrol"];

$stmt = $connect - > prepare("UPDATE users u SET 
        u.usertype = ? ,
        u.email = ? ,
        u.level = ? ,
        u.exp = ? ,
        u.money = ? ,
        u.ninjarank = ? ,
        u.avatar = ? ,
        u.village = ? ,
        u.clan = ? ,
        u.guild = ? ,
        u.healthpoint = ? ,
        u.chakrapoint = ? ,
        u.ninjutsu = ? ,
        u.taijutsu = ? ,
        u.genjutsu = ? ,
        u.senjutsu = ? ,
        u.talent = ? ,
        u.chakra = ? ,
        u.health = ? ,
        u.chakracontrol = ?
        WHERE userid = ? ");
        $stmt - > bind_param("isiiisssssiiiiiiiiiii",
            $usertype,
            $email,
            $level,
            $exp,
            $money,
            $ninjarank,
            $avatar,
            $village,
            $clan,
            $guild,
            $healthpoint,
            $chakrapoint,
            $ninjutsu,
            $taijutsu,
            $genjutsu,
            $senjutsu,
            $talent,
            $chakra,
            $health,
            $chakracontrol,
            $userid
        );

        $stmt - > execute(); $stmt - > close(); $connect - > close();
?>
```

so to test this it i am adding +1000 to $money each time when users log out and updating database but nothing happens , i tried do a simple insert and update function with a one column but that didt work ether so i am ges that the problem is with ajax function , i have tried to send a value trough him but same thing got no result

Comment: Yes!!! Your problem is with ajax because you are not submitting any Data to the PHP.... That is why...

Comment: You can't use session here. Send data through ajax.

Comment: He can you session, why he can't? session in ajax is ok. I think you need to `$('#logout').click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); .... }` to prevent the link to trigger. When you done, use `window.location.href='/'`

Comment: inside alert you given username. where that variable defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is Ideal to suggest that you extract your $_SESSION Data into an Array, encode it into JSON and then set it as a Javascript Global Variable, so that it is accessible to your JS Script. Here's how:

**PHP: THE LOG OUT PAGE**

```
        // FILENAME: logout.php     // THE LOGOUT PAGE HAS ALL THE $_SESSION DATA SO YOU COULD JUST EXTRACT IT AND PASS IT TO JS:

        // CREATE AN ARRAY TO HOLD YOUR $_SESSION DATA TO BE PASSED TO JAVASCRIPT;          
        $arrSessionData = array(        
            'userid'        => $_SESSION["userid"],
            'usertype'      => $_SESSION["usertype"],
            'email'         => $_SESSION["email"],
            'level'         => $_SESSION["level"],
            'exp'           => $_SESSION["exp"],
            'money'         => intval($_SESSION["money"]) + 1000,
            'ninjarank'     => $_SESSION["ninjarank"],
            'avatar'        => $_SESSION["avatar"],
            'village'       => $_SESSION["village"],
            'clan'          => $_SESSION["clan"],
            'guild'         => $_SESSION["guild"],
            'healthpoint'   => $_SESSION["healthpoint"],
            'chakrapoint'   => $_SESSION["chakrapoint"],
            'ninjutsu'      => $_SESSION["ninjutsu"],
            'taijutsu'      => $_SESSION["taijutsu"],
            'genjutsu'      => $_SESSION["genjutsu"],
            'senjutsu'      => $_SESSION["senjutsu"],
            'talent'        => $_SESSION["talent"],
            'chakra'        => $_SESSION["chakra"],
            'health'        => $_SESSION["health"],
            'chakracontrol' => $_SESSION["chakracontrol"],

        );

        // NOW CREATE A GLOBAL JS OBJECT THAT WOULD BE ACCESSIBLE TO YOUR JAVASCRIPT FILE:
        $SCRIPT_OUT     = '<script type="text/javascript">' . PHP_EOL;
        $SCRIPT_OUT    .= 'var _SESSION_DATA = ' . json_encode($arrSessionData ) . ";";
        $SCRIPT_OUT    .= '</script>' . PHP_EOL;

        // ECHO OUT THE SCRIPT SO THAT THE VARIABLE: _SESSION_DATA IS NOW GLOBAL:
        echo $SCRIPT_OUT;

    ?>
```

**JAVSCRIPT: THE AJAX SECTION**

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function ($) {
            $(document).ready(function (e) {
                $('#logout').click(function() {
                    // PREVENT DEFAULT BEHAVIOUR TILL YOUR AJAX PROCESSING IS DONE.
                    // HOWEVER, EVEN IF YOU DON'T PREVENT THE DEFAULT, YOUR SCRIPT WILL WORK JUST FINE BUT....
                    // IN YOUR CASE YOU DON'T NEED TO BECAUSE ALL YOU WANT IS UPDATE THE USER DATA USING THE SESSION DATA
                    // AND NORMALLY LOG THE USER OUT WITHOUT ANY DRAMA...
                    // UNCOMMENT THE LINE BELOW IF YOU STILL NEED IT...
                    /* e.preventDefault();   */ 
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'updateusers.php',
                        data: {'jsonData': _SESSION_DATA},
                        async: 'false',

                        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                            // YOU CAN NOW PROCEED WITH COMPLETE LOGOUT OF THE USER OR WHAT EVER.
                        }
                    });

                    alert(username);
                });
            });
        })(jQuery);

    </script>
```

**PHP: UPDATE_USERS.PHP FILE**

```
    <?php
        // FILENAME: updateusers.php
        require "mysql.php";
        // session_start();      // <== NO NEED FOR SESSION; YOU HAVE THE DATA YOU NEED...

        // GET THE  DATA (ARRAY) FROM AJAX
        $sessionData        = isset($_POST['jsonData']) ? $_POST['jsonData'] : null;

        // IF THE DATA IS NOT NULL, CONTINUE WITH YOUR UPDATE LOGIC....
        if(!is_null($sessionData)){

            // EXTRACT THE DATA AND ALSO DO YOUR UPDATE WITHIN THIS IF BLOCK....
            $userid         = $sessionData["userid"];
            $usertyp        = $sessionData["usertype"];
            $email          = $sessionData["email"];
            $level          = $sessionData["level"];
            $exp            = $sessionData["exp"];
            $money          = intval($sessionData["money"]) + 1000;
            $ninjarank      = $sessionData["ninjarank"];
            $avatar         = $sessionData["avatar"];
            $village        = $sessionData["village"];
            $clan           = $sessionData["clan"];
            $guild          = $sessionData["guild"];
            $healthpoint    = $sessionData["healthpoint"];
            $chakrapoint    = $sessionData["chakrapoint"];
            $ninjutsu       = $sessionData["ninjutsu"];
            $taijutsu       = $sessionData["taijutsu"];
            $genjutsu       = $sessionData["genjutsu"];
            $senjutsu       = $sessionData["senjutsu"];
            $talent         = $sessionData["talent"];
            $chakra         = $sessionData["chakra"];
            $health         = $sessionData["health"];
            $chakracontrol  = $sessionData["chakracontrol"];


            // UPDATE THE USER'S DATA BASED ON THE VALUES ABOVE...
            $stmt = $connect->prepare("UPDATE users u SET
            u.usertype=?,
            u.email=?,
            u.level=?,
            u.exp=?,
            u.money=?,
            u.ninjarank=?,
            u.avatar=?,
            u.village=?,
            u.clan=?,
            u.guild=?,
            u.healthpoint=?,
            u.chakrapoint=?,
            u.ninjutsu=?,
            u.taijutsu=?,
            u.genjutsu=?,
            u.senjutsu=?,
            u.talent=?,
            u.chakra=?,
            u.health=?,
            u.chakracontrol=?
             WHERE userid= ?");
            $stmt->bind_param("isiiisssssiiiiiiiiiii",
                $usertype,
                $email,
                $level,
                $exp,
                $money,
                $ninjarank,
                $avatar,
                $village,
                $clan,
                $guild,
                $healthpoint,
                $chakrapoint,
                $ninjutsu,
                $taijutsu,
                $genjutsu,
                $senjutsu,
                $talent,
                $chakra,
                $health,
                $chakracontrol,
                $userid
            );

            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->close();
            $connect->close();

        }
    ?>
```

I hope this helps a little....

Comment: i dont understand one thing hare u make array into logout.php but you call updateusers,php with ajax not logout ??

Comment: @yahoo5000    Yes... because inside of logout.php, You still have the $_SESSION Data available to you. That is why we also exposed the Session Array as JSON Data to JAVASCRIPT using a global Variable so that your AJAX Script (JS) has access to the Global Variable. But You have to be sure that the AJAX Script (JS) is inside the logout.php File. Hope this clears things a little bit.

Comment: so i rather make array inside main file where js script is

Comment: i made like this cuz i your way u have to echo script out and i do not realy whant that somewhere will be writed something from that array so i did like this but i get fail ones i log out i checked my syntax are good ,https://jsfiddle.net/ps5xmz8d/

Answer (score 0):

I did some change in your code and I tried in my pc it's working fine. Try following code. Hope it may solve your problem.

```
$('#logout').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'updateusers.php',
            async: 'false',
            data: "logout=makeLogout",
            dataType: "text",
            success:function(data)
            {
              alert(data);
            },
            error:function(xhr,ajaxOptions,throwErrors) {
              alert(throwErrors);
            }
        });

        alert(username);
    });
```